# US Consulate keeping my passport for a long period for Visa processing?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

Long story short I applied for a US Visa around October '18, refused on the spot but I was asked for further background documents, which I provided.

Fast-forward to January '19, I was asked to drop off my passport at the consulate again, I asked the officer if my visa was approved, to which she answered yes, expect to pick up your passport in the designated postal office in 3-4 days.

Fast-forward 2 weeks later and I get nothing, I email the consulate and I'm told that "additional administrative processing is required before we can continue with your visa issuance". And now it has been nearly 50 days and I haven't received my passport nor my visa. To me, it seems incredibly unreasonable to withhold someone's passport for that long... I've had to cancel several plans because I don't even have a passport at the moment.

Comment: Ok, so you've been in contact with the consulate and they've replied. Other than 'contact them again' what do you think we can add?

Comment: Does your country issue second passports for these situations? Some countries will give you a second passport if you need to have your first passport out for visa applications and that conflicts with your travel plans. That would allow you to keep your passport with the US Consulate for their processing and not have to cancel any other trips.

Comment: What is your question? You can **demand** your passport back and lose out on the visa, or keep quiet and near it. These consular types have no respect for individuals. Background checks can be done without holding your passport, but then I guess beggars cannot be choosers and getting a visa at all is supposedly a **privilege**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not a question, just a post submission rant.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn It's hardly a rant.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an actual question here. You have explained the background, but you forgot to ask a question?

Comment: If you add which consulate, this question could help other people (knowing that one consulate seems to be understaffed).